# Spring JPA Hibernate "Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate"

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

i aims make working hibernate with JPA EntityManager in order to not change code if i change my ORM in the future, i get an error "Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate" when i launch my class test, bellow source code :

Config.java :

```
package repository.jpa;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

     private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH = "hibernate.max_fetch_depth";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size";
        private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
        private static final String[] ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {"a.b.c.entities", "a.b.c.converters"};

        
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setName("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                //.addScript("classpath:db/schema.sql")
                //.addScript("classpath:db/data.sql")
                .build();

    }
    
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJtaDataSource(dataSource1());
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("model");
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("unit1");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaHibernateProperties());
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        
        
        return localEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
            
    private HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter =new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        
        return txManager;
    }
    
    private Properties jpaHibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        //properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH));
        //properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE));
        //properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE));
        //properties.put(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_DATABASE_ACTION, "none");
        //properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER, "false");      
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, true);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
       
        return properties;       
    }
    @Bean
    public PersonRepository personRepository() {
        return new PersonRepository();
    }
    
}
```

PersonRepository.java :

```
package repository.jpa;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


import model.Person;
import repository.jdbctemplate.IPersonRepository;

public class PersonRepository implements IPersonRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit1")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private EntityManager session() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    //@Transactional( value= TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Person getPersonById(String id) {
        long idLong = Long.valueOf(id);
        return (Person) session().createQuery("from Person where id = :id").setParameter("id", idLong).getResultList();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTableCreated(String tableName) {
        int count = (int) session().createQuery("select count(*) from shema_information where table_name='PERSON'").getSingleResult();
                
        return count > 0 ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public void createPersonTable() {
        session().createQuery("create table Person(id number, name varchar, salary float)");

    }

    @Override
    public int insertPerson(long id, String name, float salary) {
        int count = session().createQuery("insert into Person values(?,?,?)").setParameter("id", id)
                .setParameter("name", name).setParameter("salary", salary).executeUpdate();
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getPerosnLinesAsListMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return session().createQuery("select p from Person p").getResultList();
    }

}
```

PersonRepositoryTest.java :

```
package test.repository.jpa;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.util.List;


import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import model.Person;
import repository.jdbctemplate.IPersonRepository;
import repository.jpa.Config;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/schema.sql")
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/data.sql")
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    IPersonRepository personRepo;
    //@Test
    public void getPersonById_RightId_NotNull() {
        Person person = personRepo.getPersonById("2");
        assertNotNull(person);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void findAll_2Ecords_OK() {
        List<Person> persons = personRepo.findAll();
        assertEquals(2,persons.size());
    }
}
```

bellow the error stack obtained when launch PersonRepositoryTest.java class test :

```
15:16:02.459 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader - Static select for entity model.Person [NONE]: select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.name as name2_0_0_, person0_.salary as salary3_0_0_ from Person person0_ where person0_.id=?
15:16:02.486 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator - No actions specified; doing nothing
15:16:02.487 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository - Checking 0 named HQL queries
15:16:02.487 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository - Checking 0 named SQL queries
15:16:02.491 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl - EventListenerRegistry access via ServiceRegistry is deprecated.  Use `sessionFactory.getEventEngine().getListenerRegistry()` instead
15:16:02.496 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@6b63abdc
15:16:02.496 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Registering SessionFactory: 43bdb8fe-219f-41d8-8c7e-48775ee764e5 (<unnamed>)
15:16:02.496 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
15:16:02.497 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'unit1'
15:16:02.526 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'unit1'
15:16:02.526 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: unit1
    persistence provider classname: null
    classloader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@5387f9e0
    excludeUnlistedClasses: true
    JTA datasource: org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@21282ed8], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
15:16:02.747 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@7d66e544 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 4, missCount = 1]
15:16:02.754 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [test.repository.jpa.PersonRepositoryTest.findAll_2Ecords_OK]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
15:16:02.835 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator - Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
15:16:02.842 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1428777808<open>)] for JPA transaction
15:16:02.850 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JtaPlatform#retrieveTransactionManager returned null
15:16:02.851 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - Unable to access TransactionManager, attempting to use UserTransaction instead
15:16:02.851 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JtaPlatform#retrieveUserTransaction returned null
15:16:02.851 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JtaPlatform#retrieveTransactionManager returned null
15:16:02.851 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - Unable to access TransactionManager, attempting to use UserTransaction instead
15:16:02.851 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JtaPlatform#retrieveUserTransaction returned null
15:16:02.853 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Could not rollback EntityManager after failed transaction begin
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.makePhysicalTransactionDelegate(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransactionDriverControl(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.<init>(TransactionImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.accessTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getTransaction(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.closeEntityManagerAfterFailedBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:506)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:279)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$0(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
15:16:02.855 [main] WARN org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@8458f04] for test method [public void test.repository.jpa.PersonRepositoryTest.findAll_2Ecords_OK()] and test instance [test.repository.jpa.PersonRepositoryTest@65f8f5ae]
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations.executeWithoutResult(TransactionOperations.java:67)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:279)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.lambda$executeSqlScripts$0(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:148)
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.makePhysicalTransactionDelegate(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransactionDriverControl(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.<init>(TransactionImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.accessTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getTransaction(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
15:16:02.856 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext [1552326679] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@65987993 testClass = PersonRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class repository.jpa.Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@28f2a10f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7fee8714, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@209da20d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@21282ed8], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
15:16:02.857 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@7d66e544 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 5, missCount = 1]
15:16:02.857 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext [1552326679] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@65987993 testClass = PersonRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class repository.jpa.Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@28f2a10f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7fee8714, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@209da20d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@21282ed8], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
15:16:02.857 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@7d66e544 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 6, missCount = 1]
15:16:02.858 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext [1552326679] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@65987993 testClass = PersonRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class repository.jpa.Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@28f2a10f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7fee8714, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@209da20d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@21282ed8], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]
15:16:02.858 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@7d66e544 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 7, missCount = 1]
15:16:02.860 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate - Retrieved ApplicationContext [1552326679] from cache with key [[MergedContextConfiguration@65987993 testClass = PersonRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class repository.jpa.Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@28f2a10f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7fee8714, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@209da20d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customiz
```

Comment: You seem not to use/didn't tag:spring-boot, but how to explain this (spring.boot.test related) output?

Comment: thank's, i don't see the output : spring.boot.test, i don' use "tag:spring-boot"